# How do I wire my form action to my controller action?

Tags: plugins, routing, controller

I'm writing my first Craft CMS plugin.

I have the following tag in my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="clientnameDonation/donateForm/donate">
```

And then I have the following controller code to handle the action:

```
namespace Craft;

class ClientnameDonation_DonateFormController extends BaseController
{
    protected $allowAnonymous = array('actionDonate',
        );

    public function actionDonate()
    {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

When I try to submit the form, I get the following error:

> Unable to resolve the request "clientnameDonation/donateForm/donate"

Is there a piece I'm missing, or is there a casing error somewhere?

I also tried just using a raw action URL like this:

> http://URL/index.php?p=actions/clientnameDonation/donateForm/donate

I get the same routing error.

Comment: Can you try the URL minus the index.php?p=. That gets me depending on my local environment every now and then. Also, make sure the plugin is installed.

Comment: This may sound insulting but have you installed the plugin?

Comment: also, what is the file name of the controller?

Comment: Believe me it's not insulting at all.  I don't know how to "install" a plugin other than adding the folder with the correct plugin infrastructure to the plugins folder.  Do I need to create a github repo of the plugin and actually install it that way?  The file path of the controller is: `craft/plugins/clientnamedonation/controllers/ClientnameDonation_DonateFormController.php`

Comment: You need to go into the control panel then 'Settings>Plugins'. If you've set it up correctly then you should see your plugin name in the list. Simply click "Install" and then your plugins file will be accessible from your templates.

Comment: Additionally I'd make sure you use something like https://pluginfactory.io/ to generate the boilerplate plugin code for you.  Reduces the chance of running into this like case sensitivity issues on case sensitive operating systems.

Comment: Ok, I DID use pluginfactory.io to generate the boilerplate.  I didn't realize I needed to activate the plugin in the UI.  When I go to Settings>Plugins I do NOT see my plugin listed there.  Also, I did try clearing the cache.

Comment: Are there any other troubleshooting steps I can take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to install your Plugin through the control panel. To do this go to 'Settings>Plugins' and if you've set it up correctly then you should see your Plugin name in the list.

Simply click "Install" and then your plugins file will be accessible from your templates.

Answer (score 2):

I had the plugin set up correctly but I didn't go into the administration menu and install the plugin via the GUI.

Comment: It happens to the best of us :)